# Eliminating server side view | Pros / Cons

Tags: php, javascript

My server, implemented in PHP, is now just a data pump.  I compose HTML on the client using JavaScript.

**Pros**

- Reduces network load (no HTML, just raw data)
- Reduces server load (server does not have to compose)

**Cons**

- Increases client load

Given these pros/cons it seems a good idea to move HTML composing to the client as long as there are no load issues at the client.

Are there any angles I have not looked at?

**From Comments / Answers**

**Possible Cons**

- Bots might fail
- Screen Readers might fail

**Additional Pros**

- Pure data is readily available for new apps on new devices

Comment: Another pro: if you want to write a mobile native UI, you're all set with a pure-data HTML API

Comment: What happens if the client doesn't support JavaScript? If there is no logic to do on the client side besides the templating, then don't do it on the client side.

Comment: how will people link to specific pages of your website?

Comment: @TorstenWalter it's 2012, and clients that don't support JavaScript are quite rare. You're right of course that a sacrifice is made, but we don't worry much about clients that don't support more than 256 colors anymore either.

Comment: @Pointy you seem to have an answer to everything for this, but I still haven't gotten an answer for my question. How do you allow users to link to specific pages of your website?

Comment: In 2012, assistive devices and screen readers still hardly speak JavaScript (it gets better though). And as Andreas points out below, I can turn it off, anytime (as was always the issue with form validation on the client side). It always depends on your demographic. Of course, the upside of a static webpage is full control over the output client side rendering comes at a cost. Don't get me wrong, I do Webapps for a living, but if you only have static content and no partial rendering / dynamic updates, do it server side.

Comment: @dqhendricks to handle links to pages, I use the HTML5 history API. My URLs are shown to the user with a particular pattern that the server recognizes as being "external".  That causes a forward (in the server) to the "master" page, and then that page in turn loads the content page based on what that original URL was. Whenever the master page has loaded the main content fragment, it uses the history API to set the URL to that same "external" form, so that bookmarks etc. will work properly.

Comment: @dqhendricks basically it's just done with trickery in the URL routing mechanism in the server.

Comment: Stop with editing asterisks at the end of your post titles.  Continuing to do so might result in further moderator action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some user stories that you should list under 'cons' - there are more.

- I have javascript switched off because I'm security conscious.  Your website doesn't work for me.
- When I use the back button I leave your website *(getting round this is technically quite difficult)* - ***see comments - this has been disputed***
- After using your website for a good length of time, my web browser consumes a huge amount of memory because it's lax in reclaiming memory vacated by out-of-scope objects, or because your code isn't efficient *(IE is particularly prone to this)*
- I use a mobile device whose JavaScript performance is poor compared to a desktop - your website appears very slow for me.
- I use a screen reader - your website is unintelligible to me.
- My name is GoogleBot - your website isn't indexable.

If none of this bothers you - go right ahead.

**As an aside**

I should add - I am altogether *not* against this kind of application at all.  If done properly the client experience can surpass that experienced with the traditional click, GET, click, POST, click, GET etc etc website.  Indeed in my current project I have been working on a pure-javascript application as a QA aide and prototype for my organisation's site.

But we will certainly not use such a thing as our only web presence.

Comment: [GoogleBot can index Ajax Sites](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992)

Comment: @TorstenWalter how bout bing bot? yahoo bot? someobscuresearchenginebot?

Comment: Making the back button work is not really that hard.  Screen readers generally understand dynamic DOM manipulation. Memory leaks can be controlled by judicious use of solid frameworks (to avoid DOM-JS memory mixing).

Comment: @TorstenWalter hmmm - I don't think you should hang a decision to omit non-javascript functionality because google has been a bit clever.  Equally - you have to provide html snapshots of the data - which would have to be kept up to date and therefore require HTML generation on the server - meaning you still haven't omitted the need to produce HTML on the server; meaning you might as well ditch the whole-client-does-it approach unless you can gracefully degrade.

Comment: @Pointy so does googlebot only index one page using your entire website's content in this scenario?

Comment: @AndrasZoltan I was just pointing out that Google does index AJaX sites, not that it necessarily is the right thing to do in all cases. (See my comments above)

Comment: @dqhendricks that I cannot say - I've been generally working on subscription-only web applications for the past ... geez, 13 years now, so what Google does has always been completely unimportant to me. I agree that that may be a gigantic consideration for a lot of people.

Comment: @TorstenWalter - cool - sorry if it seemed like I was jumping down your throat.  Google's solution is, as is often the case, actually really quite useful if you're willing to put in the little bit of work server side to help them get the data!

Comment: @AndrasZoltan No offense taken ;)

Answer (score 2):

define "client load", please

also, keep in mind that unless you set up the data to be served from the same domain, JS can't actually consume it, unless you circumvent XSS via JSONP

The creating of html in javascript can be a lot to manage after a while unless you use a template system in JS, which is essentially just an MVC on the client.

PERFORMANCE: JS is much faster that PHP so i dont see the slowness of JS being a problem, however, the DOM itself is slow when interacting with it, so the less interaction with the DOM, the better.

the best thing about your idea is that the "page load" will be "faster" according to crawlers since the synchronous load of the page is what counts.

But then you must consider that you may have problems getting your content crawled if the data is populated in the dom asynchronously

Comment: Single-page applications are pretty common nowadays.

Comment: sure they are -- often, a lot more goes into them than people give them credit for. and the issues surrounding serving content for single page applications is helping create an ecosystem for things like Node.js. But thats still server side code.

Comment: Oh I get the effort part, believe me :-) But processing page (fragment) templates client-side is what I'm talking about.

Comment: yes, I am in favor of this, as long as he isn't abusing the DOM

Comment: I take a firm stand against DOM abuse :-)

Comment: we gotta fight for the DOM lol